# Array prop returns Observer so can't access at [0]

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I passed Array but got Observer here's my code:

In Component1

```
data() {
   return {
     myWords: [],
        }
   }
//...
await axios.post(this.serverUrl + router, {
            voca: text,
            category: this.buttonGroup.category.text
          })
          .then(res => {
            this.myWords.push({
              voca: this.voca,
              vocaHeader: this.vocaHeader,
              category: res.data.savedVoca.category,
              date: res.data.savedVoca.date,
              id: res.data.savedVoca._id
              })
            this.myWords.push({voca:"test"})
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
          })
```

In Component2

```
 props: {
      myWordsProp: {
        type: Array,
        default: () => ([])
      },
    },
mounted() {
    console.log(this.myWordsProp)
    console.log(this.myWordsProp[0]) //returns undefined
},
```

And I expected an Array but I get Observer so I can't get values from this.myWordsProp[0] why?

```
//this.myWordsProp
[__ob__: Observer]
0: {
  category: "ETC"
  date: "2018-11-21T15:31:28.648Z"
  id: "5bf57a503edf4e0016800cde"
  voca: Array(1)
  vocaHeader: Array(1)
  ... 
  }
1: {__ob__: Observer}
length: 2
__ob__: Observer {value: Array(2), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
__proto__: Array

//this.myWordsProp[0]
undefined
```

---

I found a clue that when I test it outside of axios it worked as I expected.

Answer (score 2):

`Vue` wraps data and props into reactive objects.  Use `vue-devtools plugin` in your browser as an alternative to viewing the `ugly observer` in the console.

In your code, the object behaves correctly. It’s only in the console that it ‘looks’ different.

Anyway, you can also click on the `...` to expand the node and get the value from the console.

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools

Comment: Do you mean vue-devtool for chrome? I tried launch it and refresh my web but still same and can't get this.myWordsProp[0]

Comment: yes, the dev tools.  They open in another window.  Nothing you can do about chrome’s console...

Comment: I tried dev tools but, got a no clue why I can't get this.myWordsProp[0]...

Comment: Have you tried the original syntax for mounted? https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted

Comment: @muka.gergely What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution It's because of sending props before get data from server.

This is my whole of postVocas function It returns promise

```
postVocas: function (voca) {
        if (!voca || voca.length < 1) return
        let router = "/api/voca"

        let text = ""
        text += `${this.vocaHeader[0].english}, ${this.vocaHeader[0].korean}\n`
        voca.forEach((x, index) => {
          text += `${voca[index].english}, ${voca[index].korean}\n`
        })

        return axios.post(this.serverUrl + router, {
          voca: text,
          category: this.buttonGroup.category.text
        }).then(res => {
          this.myWords.push({
            voca: this.voca,
            vocaHeader: this.vocaHeader,
            category: res.data.savedVoca.category,
            date: res.data.savedVoca.date,
            id: res.data.savedVoca._id
          })
        }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
      },
```

And await till get data from server. 
This one is function where execute My postVocas function.

```
  sendVocaToTable: async function () {
    let reformedText = this.reformText(this.text)
    this.voca = this.formatTextToVoca(reformedText)

    await this.postVocas(this.voca)

    this.$router.push({
      name: 'Table',
      params: {
        vocaProp: this.voca,
        tableHeaderProp: this.vocaHeader
      }
    })
  },
```